# EntityFramework Core relation to composite key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Consider the following database tables. Unfortunately the tables cannot be altered in any way.

[image: Database schema]

`Houses` has an auto-increment ID field named `Id`, a string field named `Name` and an integer field named `AreaId`. The latter is not a foreign key to the `Areas` table.

`Areas` has a composite key consisting of `AreaId`, `CountryId` and `LangId`. An Area with the same `AreaId` can exist but with different `CountryId` and `LangId`. E.g.: There can be two rows with the same `AreaId` but different `LangId`.

NOTE: Why does a `House` have multiple `Area`s? A `House` doesn't have multiple `Area's, it only has one`Area`. The`Area`s table has a composite key, meaning that a specific row will have multiple translations. E.g.: Area ID 5 might have LangId 5 for English and LangId 3 for Spanish.

The two tables are described by the following two C# classes.

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? AreaId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AreaId")]
    public List<Area> Areas { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public int AreaId { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public string LangId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The composite key is defined in the context, exactly as stated in the docs.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Area>()
        .HasKey(a => new { a.AreaId, a.CountryId, a.LangId });
}
```

For example let's get a list of all the Houses in the database, including their respective areas.

```
_context.Houses.Include(h => h.Areas).ToList();
```

The following SQL is generated in the output window and the resulting List contains Houses incorrectly matched with the Areas.

```
SELECT [a].[AreaId], [a].[CountryId], [a].[LangId], [a].[Name]
FROM [Areas] AS [a]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [Houses] AS [h]
    WHERE [a].[AreaId] = [h].[Id])
ORDER BY [a].[Id]
```

As you can see, EntityFramework relates `[a].[AreaId]` with `[h].[Id]` and not `[h].[AreaId]`. How can I express this relationship in EF?

Comment: can you show the code of configuration on composite key ?

Comment: I've edited the question, adding the configuation of the composite key

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Quite strange db design btw, even illogical - how 1 house be in several areas etc. Anyway.

Comment: Its actually translations. You can have two Area rows with `ID` 1. The first one will have `LangId` 5 and `Title` "Plaza". The second one will have `LangId` 6 and `Title` "Square". They both have `ID` 1 though

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You won't be able to map this correctly in EF. If you want `House` to refer to `Area`, the foreign key should consist of the same fields as `Area`'s composite key, otherwise EF won't accept the mapping. A work-around could be to skip the mapping and to join the entities manually when necessary, but that conceals the real issue: **poor design**.

The major design flaw is that you have to duplicate an `Area` when translations are added. Now the question is -- and always will be -- Which record represents my physical `Area` entity? The basic premise of a relational database is that entities are represented by *unique* records. Your design violates that core principle.

> Unfortunately the tables cannot be altered in any way.

Well, they *should* be! Leaving it this way shouldn't even be considered. You shouldn't work with a warped relational model, it's too pivotal for smooth application development.

The model, as I can piece it together from your description, should probably be something like this:

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? AreaId { get; set; }
    public Area Area { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // E.g. the name in a default language
    public ICollection<AreaTranslation> AreaTranslations { get; set; }
}

public class AreaTranslation
{
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string LocalizedName { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

For this model you need one explicit mapping instruction (EF will infer the rest):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AreaTranslation>()
            .HasKey(a => new { a.AreaId, a.LanguageId });
```

You see that `Area` now genuinely represents a physical area out there. A `House` now naturally has one `Area`, not this weird collection of `Area`s that must be considered as one area somehow. The various languages come into play by the `AreaTranslation` junction class. I assume that an `Area` belongs to one `Country`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I have inherited the database, it's not my design (I'm not an database architect, but I can use some common sense). You gave me some solid points to strengthen my position for a new schema